# Cannot create Nuget package that has xunit as dependency

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package, xunit, dotnet-cli

Steps

1. Create a new .NETStandard 2.0 project e.g ClassLibrary1
2. Add xunit package as dependency
3. Open the command prompt and go to the location
4. Execute following two commands to create package

Please check [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x) for more details

```
dotnet build /p:SourceLinkCreate=true -v:n -c:Release -p:ci=true

dotnet pack -v:n -c=Release --no-build --include-source --include-symbols --output .\bin
```

**Result**: Package not created

Instead of xunit if you add any other dependency it works, for example NUnit and test framework, or Newtonsoft.Json. I have also tried with msbuild command, same result

Is there anything I am missing, or it's a bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This github issue](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1520) says the behaviour is by design and your library needs the `IsPackable` setting in .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you both Justinas Marozas and MJK for the solution.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you.  Wasted half a day to a day on this one dumb issue.